# WordPress Custom Menu Admin helper plugin

Tags: plugins, menus, sub-menu

I'm creating learning system in WordPress and I have a lot of pages instead of post. Those pages needs to be in a custom menu with two sub items. It gets really confusing to add pages to the menus because the add to menu section is so tiny. Also some of the sub-pages doesn't show up indented.

Is there a way to make that bigger thru a plugin? To make it more uncluttered. Here's the view of my menu right now.

[image]

and sample of my menu structure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to functions.php, or put the CSS into a css file which is loaded in the admin screen. This will let the box become resizable, so you can make it taller and see more pages/checkboxes at once.

```
function wp191833_resize_menu_list() {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    #wpwrap .categorydiv div.tabs-panel,
    #wpwrap .customlinkdiv div.tabs-panel,
    #wpwrap .posttypediv div.tabs-panel,
    #wpwrap .taxonomydiv div.tabs-panel,
    #wpwrap .wp-tab-panel {
        resize: vertical;
        max-height: none;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'wp191833_resize_menu_list' );
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @RadGh - didn't know you can actually edit the CSS in the admin area. Your code doesn't work on mine though but this one did: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/apply-custom-css-to-admin-area/ Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Not sure why my code didn't work for you. Anyway, the proper way would be to use the action `admin_enqueue_scripts` and then insert a .css file using `wp_enqueue_style`. That way you can keep your CSS separate from your PHP and it can also be cached by the browser. Good luck!